Windows services that is stuck in starting
Serices applications are stuck in started status
I have tried to reboot the server still same issue
I have done sc queryex “<service_display_name>” for all that are stuck "started" and killed them
taskkill /f /pid
I am expecting the services to show running instead of started
Stuck on started
Status running

It is not stuck in starting, the screenshot shows many services as being started, which means the same as running. The screenshot with started services seem to come from an ancient Windows Server version, am I right? Recent versions call this status running.
